# Invalid select in group by clause in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am using two tables in my project. Both tables are shown in diagram. Project is in VB.net 2005 and SQL Server 2005.

[image: Schema]

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    NorthGangotri.DName, NorthGangotri.DLName, NorthGangotri.Place, 
    NorthGangotri.add1 , donor_family_detail.* 
FROM 
    NorthGangotri, donor_family_detail 
WHERE 
    NorthGangotri.NGCode = donor_family_detail.NGCode 
GROUP BY 
    donor_family_detail.NGCode
```

But when I try to execute it gives following error:

[image: Error]

Comment: `GROUP BY donor_family_detail.NGCode` will produce *one* row for each distinct `NGCode` value - but that may be derived from *multiple* rows which each have different values for `DName`, `DLName`, `Place`, etc. The server doesn't know what values to select for those other columns.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago)

Answer (score 2):

If you add a Group By clause to a query, you have certain restrictions in the SELECT list. It can contain only columns that are part of the group by or aggregate expressions. 
First question is, why do you use a GROUP BY in the first place? In which respect do you want to group the result? Then add the columns you want to group by in the SELECT list and add aggregates as desired, e.g.

```
SELECT donor_family_detail.NGCodeNorthGangotri.DName, COUNT(*)
FROM NorthGangotri, donor_family_detail 
WHERE NorthGangotri.NGCode = donor_family_detail.NGCode 
GROUP BY donor_family_detail.NGCode
```

This returns the number of rows (of the combined tables) grouped by NGCode. 

Please have a look at the documentation of the [GROUP BY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause. It contains several examples that help to understand the topic and support you when transferring this to the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You are not aggregating any data in you query so you probably should drop `group by` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NorthGangotri.DName, NorthGangotri.DLName, NorthGangotri.Place,
NorthGangotri.add1 , donor_family_detail.* 
FROM NorthGangotri
INNER JOIN donor_family_detail on NorthGangotri.NGCode = donor_family_detail.NGCode
```

also you should use `join` to connect both tables.

Comment: then how i hide duplicate values?

Comment: Try `distinct` keyword [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)